# How can I fix a broken face on a kitchen drawer?

Tags: repair

I have a silverware drawer that the face broke off when it was slammed shut.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to re-attach it.  I've tried using gorilla glue but that didn't work to well because the surfaces aren't flat (some of the fiberwood is broken).  Anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How was it originally attached?

Comment: Also, a photo might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try some corner braces and short wood screws.  You probably want to pre-drill some holes so you don't split the wood.

Comment: Used the corner brace and the drawer is good as new.  Thanks!